# AngularJs - Sharing controller between pages

Tags: angularjs

Can same controller be used in multiple pages in AngularJS, if yes then how do you preload the data from server for each of the shared pages differently? Can ng init be used to resolve this issue?

Comment: why do you want to share controllers? If you want to share logic between pages then you use services/factories. If you want to share UI's then maybe you can stick parts into a directive. But you never generally need to share controllers

Comment: @CallumLinington, I think that' would be the best answer, why not post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Victor didnt think it really answered the question, just proposed another perspective.

Comment: I have to load data for pages from server and having individual controller for each page will add to the number of files. My controllers have a single http get call to the server and few other methods

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to share controllers? If you want to share logic between pages then you use services/factories. If you want to share UI's then maybe you can stick parts into a directive. But you never generally need to share controllers.

If number of files is what worries you, concatenate all your JavaScript files into one.

Comment: I am new to angularjs and its possible i will be asking and putting lame comments please bear with me. I still will not be able to get rid of the huge number of controllers, If my pages donot have any logic just fetching data from the server, why not have onload kind of functionality where i can specify the method name

Comment: @maverick192003, don't worry, this is the whole point of the exercise.  Now, I'm afraid I don't understand your issue very well.  I think I would still have a separate controller for each different page, even if it does very little.

Comment: Thanks @Victor, I have to load data from the server upon page load(many pages having similar behavior) if there was an option to specify which method to call on pageLoad i could have provided different methods in the same controller and used it across the pages. Can i specify method name using ng init?